# Fire php block with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm parsing some form data into Ajax and looking to fire a block of php code.

So in the code I'm currently alerting out the email address on submit, I want to parse this into the `newsletter_signup` function and run the php block of code at the very bottom, with the email address from the form going into the php.

How can I do that?

```
  <form action="/event" method="POST" id="signupForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="mc_newsletter_add">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[source]" value="newsletter">
    <input checked=checked type="checkbox" name="data[newsletter_onetime]" id="newsletter_onetime" class="newsletter-optins">
    <input checked=checked type="checkbox" name="data[promos]" id="promos" class="newsletter-optins">

    <input class="modal-newsletter-input" id="EmailAddress" name="data[customers_email_address]" placeholder="Enter your email here" required="required" type="email" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])){echo $_GET['email'];}?>" aria-required="true">
    <input class="modal-newsletter-signup" id="newslettersignup" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Yes, sign me up" />
  </form>

  <script>
    $("#signupForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: form.attr('action'),
               data: form.serialize(),
               success: function(data)
               {
                   console.log(data); //data contain response from your php script
                   register_signup();
                   newsletter_signup(email);
                   form.replaceWith("<br /><p>Thanks for signing up!</p>");
               }
             });

    });

    function register_signup(){
      ga( 'send', 'event', 'Newsletter Sign Up', 'submit' );
    }

    function newsletter_signup(email){

      $('#signupForm').load(
          "newsletter-call.php",
          {
              'key1': email,
          }
      );

    }
  </script>
```

Then this calls a php called newsletter-call.php with the following in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hit the page");
</script>
<?php $sib_tracking = new SIB_Tracking();
$email = $_POST['key1'];
$event = "marketing";
$result = $sib_tracking->track_event($email, $event); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass the email address through.

```js
newsletter_signup(email);
```

And then proceed to use it as a parameter.

```js
function newsletter_signup(email) {
   console.log(email);
}
```

As to using it in the PHP, you could use the ajax request to perform the php action before outputting it to the JavaScript function.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense on the first part, thanks. Not quite sure on the php part, could you possibly expand on that please?

Comment: Try leaving action="" empty and using a .php file as an URL on your Ajax request.
You can then use that PHP file to do anything you'd like.

Or simply perform your PHP action in the current /event file that you're requesting.

Comment: I need to keep the action because it fires something else. Is it possible to load a php file within the `newsletter_signup` function perhaps and parse the email value to that?

Comment: What does it fire? Is /event a php file?

Comment: Ok I've updated my question with my attempt. It's not hitting the php file at the moment. Could be the path or something else going wrong.